# The Process Stream class does not support writing

Tags: c#, process, stdout

I am trying to write something to a process using stream class. I am using .net 4.5. However it seems that writing is not support.

```
Process.StandardOutput.BaseStream.CanWrite
```

return false.

Is it true that Process Stream class does not support writing?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, because it's the *output* of the other process. You're only able to *read* from it. From the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardoutput(v=vs.110).aspx).

> Gets a stream used to read the output of the application.

I know it's a bit confusing, but think of it as StandardOutput *from the perspective of the process*. (Not from your perspective, as another process looking at it.)

If you want to write data for the other process to read, you'd use [`Process.StandardInput`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.standardinput(v=vs.110).aspx) instead.